# How to get the uiautoamtorviewer, which I mistakenly deleted?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, uiautomatorviewer

I have deleted the uiautomatorviewer mistakenly from my Android SDK tools folder, How can I get it back?

I have tried copying the code for uiautomatorviewer manually from the [git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/android-4.2.2_r1/uiautomatorviewer/etc/uiautomatorviewer.bat) repository and saved it to the same location but it didn't worked for me.

How can I download or get it back at the same SDK folder ?

Comment: Which operating system you're using ?

Comment: @theapache64 Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Ok, So finally I found it on Androids site itself, don't know how I missed it before, Android SDK tools can be simply downloaded from https://developer.android.com/studio

Comment: Yes, or simply you can delete the SDK folder, and AS will download the latest one for you. This seems to be a bad fix for me , as you'll have to waste your bandwidth. Other solution is to download the missing `uiautomatorviewer.jar` and `uiautomatorviewer.bat` file from online and place it in correct folders.

Comment: I think downloading only SDK tools will be much easier you just have to extract the tools folder from zip and copy to the correct folder under sdk. I have tried downloading uiautomatorviewer.bat but got no luck with that, I guess downloading SDK tools is appropriate solution to this, Still Thanks for your response.